# Handling StreamingBodyResponse on client using thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, client, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring boot 4.2. I have a service that returns StreamingBodyResponse (console output). I want to show this output in a view (preferably thymeleaf but anything is fine.) Right now it just opens a browser and streams it there.What I would like to do is show the Streaming response in a text area of a thymeleaf view and also closing this view shouldn't affect the streaming to halt and crash things on server side. It would be great if someone could point me out in the right direction.

```
 @PostMapping(value="/environment",produces =MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public StreamingResponseBody environmentSubmit(@ModelAttribute Environment environment) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String currentUserName = authentication.getName();
    Configuration configuration = Configuration.createFromPostParams(
            environment.getDriver(),
            environment.getVersion(),
            currentUserName);
    StreamingResponseBody response =executor.execute(configuration);
    return response;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to make sure that it runs asynchronously and doesn't timeout:

```
@Configuration
public static class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setDefaultTimeout(-1);
        configurer.setTaskExecutor(asyncTaskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean
    public AsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("async");
    }

}
```

[External source with same code](http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2016/02/asynchronous-streaming-request.html)